# In JS, what is this feature called?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to learn about this feature of javascript I keep seeing in code, but I don't know the name of the construction to google for...

```
var Stats = {
  onLoad: function(e) {
    // content
    this.variable++;
  },

  variable: 1
};
```

Is this way of organising functions and variables based on JSON?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an "Object Literal" - see the [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals#Object_Literals).

Answer (score 4):

It's called the [Object Literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php) syntax.
It's a superset of JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code creates an object literal (i.e. a hash map), with two entries. The first entry maps "onLoad" to an anonymous function, and the second entry maps "variable" to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I gave the answer to Richie for being first, but the link Greg gave has more examples, so I'll use both to learn of course (and others from google).

@Barry: thanks for explaining what it does, but that was not really what I was aiming at with the question :)